# not able to get stored data in localStorage correctly

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

I made a Bookmark page where the user can search, add, delete and update Bookmarks, but I'm really having a hard time to figure out how to save those Bookmarks. I researched a lot and asked several times here but I didn't get the solution. so basically the text that user add in the list it should be saved so when the page is refreshed the text doesn't disappear now I tried to save the li tag which has all the childNodes in it but it doesn't save it and I found that you can't store DOM element. so, in the end, I just figure out a way with this below code it stores and load the data when I refresh the page. but it; not working properly and the delete and edit button is not working. this took three days to find the solution and still stuck on it. am gonna post all the code so you guys can see the error. and it would really be appreciated if anybody can help, and Thanx for your time.

JAVASCRIPT

```
const search = document.querySelector('form input');
const input = document.querySelector('.add-text');
const container = document.querySelector('ul');
let items = null;
let currentItem = null;
let array = [];

const searchItems = function(e) {
  if (items) {
    let word = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    for (let item of items) {
      if (item.firstChild.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(word) !== -1) {
        item.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        item.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
}

const deleteItem = function(e) {
  currentItem = null;
  e.target.parentNode.remove();
  input.value = '';
}

const editItem = function(e) {
  currentItem = e.target.parentNode.firstChild;
  input.value = currentItem.textContent;
}

const updateItem = function(e) {
  if (currentItem) {
    currentItem.textContent = input.value;
    input.value = '';
  }else{
    alert('No Selected Text Here to Update');
    return;
  }
}

const addItem = function() {
  let val = input.value;
  if (val) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let inner = '<h1 class="text">' + val + '</h1>';
    inner += '<button class="delete">Delete</button>';
    inner += '<button class="edit">Edit</button>';
    array.push(inner);
    let stringified = JSON.stringify(array);
    localStorage.setItem('list', stringified);
    console.log(localStorage)
    li.innerHTML = inner;
    container.appendChild(li);
    input.value = '';
    currentItem = li.firstChild;  
    items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    for (let del of document.querySelectorAll('.delete')) {
      del.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
    }
    for (let edit of document.querySelectorAll('.edit')) {
      edit.addEventListener('click', editItem);
    }
  } else {
      alert('please add some text');
    return;
  }
}

function loaddata(){
  let stringified = localStorage.getItem('list');
  let listitems = JSON.parse(stringified);
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = listitems;
  container.appendChild(li);
  console.log(li);
}
loaddata();
search.addEventListener('keyup', searchItems);
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', addItem);
document.querySelector('#update').addEventListener('click', updateItem);
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #f1efef;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 18%;
  color: navy;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 5vh;
  left: 10%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 19px;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #e1dfdf;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6vh;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

li h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: navy;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height: 5vh;
  top: -5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  left: 0;
}

li button {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 6px;
  top: 1vh;
  height: 4vh;
  background: blue;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

div div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div div input {
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}

div div button {
  position: relative;
  left: 8%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 5vh;
  margin: 0 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h2>JavaScript CRUD Bookmark</h2>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="search">
  </form>
  <ul></ul>
  <div>
    <input class="add-text" type="text" placeholder="Add Text">
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <button id="update">update</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: localStorage only stores strings, nothing else. So, to store an array, you need to stringify it, you can use something like `var arrayStr = JSON.stringify(array)`

Comment: Calvin Nunes - but this code does store and load the data but just like I said above it's not working as it should maybe I'm not getting the data in a proper way

Comment: you can't store data in localStorage, only **strings**, that's why you need to stringify and parse... if you are getting error when stringify, then it's because you structured the array or object in  wrong format (such as worng commas or symbols that can't be used in JSON format). *Probably*, for storing HTML Elements will require you to get the element `outerHTML` then stringify it.

Answer (score 2):

LocalStorage only stores strings, nothing else. Luckily, there is a way to convert an array or object to a string, and then parse that string back to an object or array :

```
let stringified = JSON.stringify(array); // Converts the array to a string
localStorage.setItem('list', stringified );
```

and then in loaddata() :

```
let stringified = localStorage.getItem('list');
let listitems = JSON.parse(stringified); // Converts back to an array
```

Comment: Jeremy Thille - i tried this but it giving me error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Try to `console.log(stringified)`

Answer (score 2):

You can not store array directly in `localStorage`, you have to convert your array into a string since localStorage only stores string values.

`JSON.stringify(your data )` to stringify and `JSON.parse(your data from local storage)` to unstringify.

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log('myArray: ', myArray);
localStorage.setItem('myArray', JSON.stringify(myArray))

var myArrayFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myArray'));
console.log('myArrayFromLocalStorage: ', myArrayFromLocalStorage);
```

Comment: sridhar reddy - I did convert it in the string but the data is not there when I refresh the page

Comment: @KinanAlamdar Have you tried opening `inspect element` and checking in `Application -> local Storage` ?

Comment: your are setting an empty array in ` let array = [];let stringified =JSON.stringify(array);localStorage.setItem('list', stringified);`. Please check this.

Comment: sridhar reddy - sorry if I'm bothering you.  now everything is getting stored and load. but it still has bad behavior when adding new text can you please run this code and just point out to me what could be the problem

Comment: @KinanAlamdar I have made some changes to your code and attached here. https://github.com/reddysridhar53/stack/blob/master/index.html. Please add this back as an answer. Thanks!